# Silverlight listbox won't update with new itemsource

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a listbox which is bound to a generic list, whenever I removed an item from the generic list and rebind it to the listbox it still shows the deleted items. Here is the code :

```
            InventoryList.Remove(currInv);         
            lstSubMenu.ItemsSource = InventoryList;
            lstSubMenu.DisplayMemberPath = "InventoryItemName";
```

I checked the generic list and the item is being removed and there doesn't seem to be any errors in the output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource = null` before you set it to be `InventoryList`.

However, it is generally better practice to set the `ItemsSource` property once and never again. You can do this by using an `ObservableCollection`. Once you do this you can add/remove to your heart's content and not have to worry about the binding target not getting updated.